# Chartboost normal interstitials

Tags: chartboost

I integrated chartboost in my game.Test mode is working fine.My app is not at app store right now.My ques is it must for an app to be at app store to see normal interstitials in ChartBoost?

Comment: no, try with device…not in simulator.

Comment: i am trying on my ios device.

Comment: Ohh...i forgot to disable the test mode.Now its working.Thanks :-)